# Run cables through ceiling into attic

Tags: ceiling, attic, cable-management

I would like to install a wired security camera box in a closet and run the cables up into the attic to the individual cameras. How should the cables penetrate the drywall ceiling? I would like the install to look polished, minimise the access of creepy crawlies from the attic into the main house and allow for the addition of more cables in the future. The best I've been able to dream up is a short length of PVC pipe inserted in a corner of the ceiling, that gets stuffed with fiberglass insulation after running the cables, but that seems inelegant. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace "Pipe" with "**Conduit**" and "Fiberglass insulation" with "**duct seal**" (note: the electrical conduit kind, not the air duct kind) and put a couple of **bell-end fittings** on the ends to make it nice (Or just ream the sharp corners off the inside of the cut ends *really well* to be inexpensive) and you have a normal workmanlike method of achieving your goal.

It will look *more polished* if the conduit extends all the way into the security camera box, rather than just poking through the ceiling above the box.

Comment: Thanks, @Ecnerwal. Apparently, there's a whole world out there that I never knew existed.

Comment: Congratulations on 100,000

Comment: Thanks Jack. I've been trying to take a break, but my fingers keep hauling me back here as if on autopilot...